# Convex polyhedra that can be folded from convex polygons

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

This question is based on [http://www.science.smith.edu/~jorourke/Papers/FoldingPP.pdf](http://www.science.smith.edu/%7Ejorourke/Papers/FoldingPP.pdf).

Therein is stated the theorem: *Every convex polygon folds to an infinite number (a continuum) of noncongruent convex polyhedra.*

Question: What could one say in the reverse direction: given any convex polyhedron, what could one say about the polygon(s) that could fold into it? If there are convex polyhedrons that *cannot* be folded from convex polygons, then, how does one characterize convex polyhedrons (such as for example, the regular tetrahedron) that can be folded out of convex polygons?

Comment: The question of unfolding convex polyhedra to convex polygons was first posed by Shephard in 1975: Shephard, Geoffrey C. "Convex polytopes with convex nets." In *Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society*, vol. 78, no. 3, pp. 389-403. Cambridge University Press, 1975.

Comment: One minor remark (which does not answer any of your questions): Any convex polyhedron $Q$ folded from a convex polygon $P$ of $n$ vertices has at most $n+2$ vertices. This is Corollary 25.7.2 in [Geometric Folding Algorithms](http://www.gfalop.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answers the easiest question posed (1), and addresses part of the more general question (2).

> (1) "If there are convex polyhedrons that *cannot* be folded from convex polygons,..."

Yes, there is an abundance of such polyhedra. For example, let $P$ be a
cube. To unfold it to the plane, one must form surface cuts that combinatorially constitute a spanning tree of the vertices, often called a *cut tree* $T$.
(Any vertex not on $T$ will retain its 3D structure, and so obstruct
planar development.) A tree has at least two leaves. Let $v$ be
a vertex of $P$ at a leaf of $T$. Then the corresponding unfolding
forms an interior reflex angle of $3\pi/2$ locally about the image of $v$.
This is a local nonconvexity.

> (2) "how does one characterize convex polyhedrons (...) that can be folded out of convex polygons?"

Generalizing the argument above leads to a necessary condition:
A convex polyhedron $P$ needs to have
at least two vertices of curvature $\ge \pi$
(and so incident face angles $\le \pi$)
in order to serve as leaves for a cut tree $T$
that unfolds to a convex polygon.
The cube has all vertices with curvature $\pi/2$,
so there is no "home" for the leaves of $T$.

This is, however, not a complete characterization.

Comment: Thanks very much for that very nice argument, somewhat reminiscent of Fisk's proof of art gallery theorem!